# submenu in another element hides after moving the mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a sub menu list that show/hide with jquery when user hover on `li` list, each `li` shows a separate element.
Now i'm facing a problem with the jQuery code that when mouseleave, it hide the element and can't detect the hover event over this element.

The thing is, I can make it hide when switching to another list menu item and getting out of the element block. but I need it to keep showing the submenu in case the mouse is over it.

here's the code:

```js
$(".left-nav-list-view nav ul li").mouseenter(function () {
  clearMenuFlyout();
  if ($(this).data('has-submenu')) {
    var submenu_id = $(this).children('a').data('menu-id');
    $(".flyOut-nav-container").append($("[id=" + submenu_id + "]")).position({
      my: "left+1 top+0",
      at: "right top",
      of: this
    });
  }
}).on("mouseleave", function () {

});

function clearMenuFlyout(){
  $(".flyout-temp-container").append($(".flyOut-nav-container").children());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-nav-container flex-fixed">
  <nav class="left-nav-view collapsed" role="navigation">
    <div class="app-logo">
        <div class="burger-menu">
          <span class="burger-menu-icon"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="left-nav-list-view">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
          <li id="AccountingMenu" data-has-submenu="true"><a data-menu-id="AccountingMenuItems" href="#"><span>Accounting</span><i class="list-in fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
          <li id="InventoryMenu" data-has-submenu="true"><a data-menu-id="InventoryMenuItems" href="#"><span>Inventory</span><i class="list-in fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

basically `clearFlyout` function takes an already existent menu element and throw it to another div. `.flyout-temp-container` is hidden by default

Comment: Please also share your markup.

Comment: What does clearMenuFlyout do?

Comment: will share it in seconds

Comment: @rmn there you go !

Comment: @Ajaypayne , you find added info in the description, thank you!

Comment: Is there some CSS as well? How do we run this code? Can you please add all that is required and provide a working version, so people can debug it and help you out.